# AWS SAM Incorrect region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am using AWS SAM to test my Lambda functions in the AWS cloud.

This is my code for testing Lambda:

```
# Set "running_locally" flag if you are running the integration test locally
running_locally = True
 
def test_data_extraction_validate():

    if running_locally:
        lambda_client = boto3.client(
            "lambda",
            region_name="eu-west-1",
            endpoint_url="http://127.0.0.1:3001",
            use_ssl=False,
            verify=False,
            config=botocore.client.Config(
                signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED,
                read_timeout=10,
                retries={'max_attempts': 1}
            )
        )
    else:
        lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda',region_name="eu-west-1")

    ####################################################
    #   Test 1. Correct payload
    ####################################################

    with open("payloads/myfunction/ok.json","r") as f:
        payload = f.read()

    # Correct payload
    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="myfunction",
        Payload=payload
    )
    result = json.loads(response['Payload'].read())
    assert result['status'] == True
    assert result['error'] == ""
```

This is the command I am using to start AWS SAM locally:

```
sam local start-lambda -t template.yaml --debug --region eu-west-1
```

Whenever I run the code, I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ResourceNotFound) when calling the Invoke operation: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:012345678901:function:myfunction
```

I don't understand why it's trying to invoke function located in **us-west-2** when I explicitly told the code to use **eu-west-1** region. I also tried to use AWS Profile with hardcoded region - the same error.

When I switch the **running_flag** to **False** and run the code without AWS SAM everything works fine.

===== **Updated** =====

The list of env variables:

```
# env | grep 'AWS'                  
AWS_PROFILE=production
```

My AWS configuration file:

```
# cat /Users/alexey/.aws/config     
[profile production]
region = eu-west-1
```

My AWS Credentials file

```
# cat /Users/alexey/.aws/credentials
[production]
aws_access_key_id = <my_access_key>
aws_secret_access_key = <my_secret_key>
region=eu-west-1
```

Comment: Can you try to use the ARN instead of using `myfunction` as the `FunctionName`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried and error is the same

Comment: do you have any env variables? It could be that its getting the region from that variable when starting the client, even thought you have the region set manually

Comment: @PabloArriola, see the **updated** question. I guess the issue is with AWS SAM  because when I invoke function directly - it works fine, once I try to do via AWS SAM, it tries to find this function in **us-west-2**. Maybe it's cached somewhere or I am missing something

Comment: "I tried and error is the same," did you replace the function name with full ARN and still get the same error? This is odd. Did you run `sam build` after you made the change?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are actually running the correct local endpoint! In my case the problem was that I had started the lambda client with an incorrect configuration previously, and so my invocation was not invoking what I thought it was. Try killing the process on the port you have specified: `kill $(lsof -ti:3001)`, run again and see if that helps!

This also assumes that you have built the function `FunctionName="myfunction"` correctly (make sure your function is spelt correctly in the template file you use during `sam build`)